# Medir uso da CPU ou Memoria de um programa do windows em Python

Tags: python

Boa tarde!

Galera, sou novo por aqui. E sou novo com programação também.

Minha duvida é a seguinte, é possível medir o uso da CPU ou da Memoria para um programa em especifico no windows utilizando Python?

Estou escrevendo um pequeno scrypt, porem meu scrypt precisa que uma determinada tarefa seja executada por um programa do windows, e só depois que esta tarefa finalize meu scrypt continue rodando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa tarde, Thiago!

A [biblioteca psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/)  disponibiliza informações quanto ao sistema, como uso de memória e cpu.

Você começaria instalando essa biblioteca no seu ambiente virtual de python, usando o pip ou o próprio conda, e então no seu código, você deverá implementar o import:

```
import psutil
psutil.cpu_percent()
```

O código acima, por exemplo, retorna um valor em float do uso da cpu, que pode ser armazenado em uma variável, a fins de manipulação, para manter a análise constante do uso da CPU é só colocar o método " psutil.cpu_percent() " dentro de um looping, por exemplo.
Um comando muito bom dessa biblioteca também, é o: `psutil.virtual_memory()` que retorna o total de memória física, a memória disponível, a usada, a free, inativa e entre outras que podem ser armazenadas dentro de um dicionário em python se escrito dessa forma:

```
dict(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict())
```

Para pegar o uso de um determinado processo, eu fiz esse exemplo abaixo, que pega o excel:

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Aqui ele pega o nome do processo
            processName = proc.name()
            if processName == 'EXCEL.EXE':
                print(processName , ' ::: ', proc.memory_info().vms) # Esse último comando é para pegar o consumo de VMS pelo processo
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
```

A saída do programa na minha máquina foi:

> EXCEL.EXE  :::  51015680

Comment: Boa noite. é possível medir o uso da CPU o memoria para um programa especifico, tipo o excel?

Comment: Sim, editei a pergunta a fim de responder a sua questão !